# Need to show list of available audio player in android using code

Tags: android, audio-player

I want to show list of available player for audio playing but in my code is doesn’t show any player it play only sound not showing  player option,below is my code....

```
 switch (arg0.getId()) 
 {
 case R.id.rel_set_scroll_play:

           MediaPlayer mplayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
            mplayer.setDataSource(DEFAULT_STORAGE_LOCATION+"/"+contact);
            mplayer.prepare();
             } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
             }
             mplayer.start();
              Intent intenti = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        Uri datanew = Uri.parse(DEFAULT_STORAGE_LOCATION+"/"+contact);
                        intenti.setDataAndType(datanew,"audio/*");

                        try {
                            startActivity(intenti);
                        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        } 
             break;
 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you just be passing a file location to Android so it can decide how to handle the music file instead of opening and starting an internal sound player?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
switch (arg0.getId()) 
 {
   case R.id.rel_set_scroll_play:
      Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
      sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse(DEFAULT_STORAGE_LOCATION+"/"+contact);
      sendIntent.setType("audio/*");
      startActivity(sendIntent);
      break;
 }
```

if you need to show an audio player skin in your app, you have to design an audio  player and connect your code with that.
Android just give the interface for playing audio only

please refer the following link

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-project-setup--mobile-22764

Comment: @HArdik if you need to show an audio player skin in your app, you have to design an audio player and connect your code with that. Android just give the interface for playing audio only

Comment: ok i understand,but most of the time when we play any audio in android asked which player you want to use..

Answer (score 0):

I do this using this code...

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
Intent viewMediaIntent = new Intent();   
viewMediaIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);        
Uri audio Uri.parse(DEFAULT_STORAGE_LOCATION+"/"+contact);       
viewMediaIntent.setDataAndType(audio, "video/*");   
viewMediaIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
Intent ii = Intent.createChooser(viewMediaIntent, "Play Music");
startActivity(ii);
```